# How to force KOMA-Script use headers/footers as standard classes?

Tags: header-footer, koma-script

It is known that KOMA-Script has more flexibility than standard classes. One example is the ability to use any font size (e.g., 11.5pt). One problem appears though, which is headers and footers placing. In the standard classes, page numbers, e.g., in the bottom are placed wisely but in KOMA it is too close to the paper edge.

The question is how to force KOMA use the same distance for footers, headers, rules and margins as standard classes. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
A test document
\end{document}
```

which outputs the footer correctly:

[image]

Whereas using KOMA-Script:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
A test document
\end{document}
```

outputs this (undesired) behavior:

[image]

Any idea? Thank you.

**EDIT:**

The strange behavior in headers also can be shown by this example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,headsepline,twoside=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage[left=3.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pagegrid}
\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\noindent 
Some plain text just to fill paragraph lines. Some plain text just to fill paragraph lines.

\newpage     
\noindent 
Some plain text just to fill paragraph lines. Some plain text just to fill paragraph lines. Some plain text just to fill paragraph lines. Some plain text just to fill paragraph lines. Some plain text just to fill paragraph lines. Some plain text just to fill paragraph lines. Some plain text just to fill paragraph lines. Some plain text just to fill paragraph lines. Some plain text just to fill paragraph lines. 

\end{document}
```

Problems in the header are shown in the following image:

[image]

Comment: You might want to use the `includehead` and `includefoot` options of `geometry`. But if possible you shouldn't use `geometry` with koma script, but the included `typearea`.

Comment: Try the global option `emulatestandardclasses` to get as close to the standard classes as possible. Adding package `showframe` will give you an idea where head and foot actually are.

Comment: @Johannes_B The option `emulatestandardclasses` unfortunately affects also font size.

Comment: @AboAmmar Yes, it does. As close as possible. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the same `footskip` as ​used by the standard class `article` then change it to `30pt`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,
  footskip=30pt% <- added
]{geometry}
\begin{document}
A test document: \the\footskip
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Explanation:**

With a KOMA-Script class the `\footskip` is set to `3.5\baselineskip`. The standard classes `article` and `report` use `30pt` as `\footskip` while the `book` class uses `.35in` with fontsize `10pt`, `.38in` with `11pt` and `30pt` with fontsize `12pt`. If you change only the margins using package `geometry` the `\footskip` is not changed even if you use a standard class. See the following example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[
  margin=30pt,
  showframe% to show the page layout
  ]{geometry}
\begin{document}
A test document: \the\footskip
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

As you can see the page number can be also too close to the paper edge even if the standard class `article` is used. Hence the page number is not placed wisely by the standard class - its baseline is simple placed `30pt` below the text body.

So if you change the margins manually it is your task to manually adjust the `footskip`.

If the baseline of the page number should be in the middle of the white space you can use `footskip=1cm` (= half of the bottom margin). Or choose something like `footskip=\dimexpr1cm+.7ex\relax` if the page number should be nearly centered in the white space at the bottom.

---

**Update/Addition** (regarding the changed question and a comment)

Here is your second example using the packages `showframe` and `layout`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,headsepline,twoside=false]{scrbook}
\usepackage[left=3.50cm, right=2.50cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm,
%includehead,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{pagegrid}
\pagegridsetup{tl,firstcolor=blue!50}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\layout
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\lipsum[10]
\clearpage
\noindent\lipsum[10]
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

As you can see the text body starts 2.5cm below of the paper edge. Note that the KOMA option `headsepline` sets the KOMAoption `headinclude` for the KOMA package `typearea`. But you change your layout using `geometry`. So you have to tell this package that the header should be included. If you uncomment its option `includehead` in the example you get

[image]

Now the top of the header is 2.5cm below of the paper edge.

The command `\layout` from the package `layout` shows us the exact values

[image]

The top of the header is `1inch+\voffset+\topmargin` below of the paper edge. Note that `\voffset` is normally `0pt`. *With* option `includehead` this results in your 2.5cm (set by `geometry`).

The text body starts `1inch+\voffset+\topmargin+\headheight+\headskip` below of the paper edge. *Without* option `includehead` this results in 2.5cm (set by `geometry`).

Using `geometry` you can controll:

- the distance to the text body (without `includehead`) or the distance to the top of the header by the `geometry` option `top`
- the height of the head by the `geometry` option `headheight`
- the sep between header and text body by the `geometry` option `headsep`

See the [documentation of `geometry`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf) for more Information.

Comment: This is exactly what I want to avoid, manual calculations. How do you know it is 30pt? Why doesn't KOMA place footers/headers automatically in a sane way? in the middle of the white space, for example.

Comment: @AboAmmar If you want to have an automatic calculation of a *sane* textarea along with margiin settings, have a look at chapter 2 of the KOMA-documentation. As soon as you load `geometry` stuff is going on, and as soon as you manually set a margin size, you can do the rest by hand as well ;-)

Comment: @Johannes_B Yes, but KOMA has its own philosophy regarding page layout, it assumes, e.g., that header:footer = 1:2, which is not always the case. So, how can we force it use equal head and foot? If we remove `geometry` and use `typearea` and `\areaset[]{}{}` it automatically chooses this 1:2 logic.

Comment: @AboAmmar You can use `marginratio={1:1,1:1}` for geometry to make the horizontal as well as the vertical margins equal. But this will not even slightly change the fact that the author of `KOMA-script` decided the `footskip` to be dynamically calculated in dependence of the font size; whereas the standard classes define a `footskip` of 30 pt in the `clo` files.

Comment: @AboAmmar I have extended my answer.

Comment: @esdd (+1) for this great addition. One last request and consider your answer accepted; how to control the header also? When I set `top=2.5cm`  I get the head rule at 1.7cm and the text at 3.2cm from top of the paper, I expect the rule to be at exactly 2.5cm. How to control distance between head rule and text? The documentation only mentions `headheight`, every thing else is unclear or forgotten altogether!!

Comment: @esdd Please see the explanation in the edited part of my question.

Comment: @AboAmmar I have extended my answer again.

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest not to use the package geometry. If you remove it, you'll see that your pagination moves to a better position.
If you need to adjust the margin, do so by using KOMA's capabilities, changing the division (by using the KOMA option DIV=) and giving a small piece of the type area to the margins e.g.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt, paper=a4, DIV=11]{scrartcl}

\AfterCalculatingTypearea{
    \addtolength{\evensidemargin}{0.1\textwidth}
    \setlength{\textwidth}{0.9\textwidth}
    \setlength{\marginparwidth}{%
        \dimexpr 1.5\evensidemargin+0.5\marginparsep\relax}
    \setlength{\marginparsep}{0.5\marginparsep}
}
\KOMAoptions{DIV=last}
```

Some information about adjusting the division and the type area can be found in chapter 2 of the KOMA documentation, esp. 2.2 and 2.6.

HTH, Dario